# How can I find the short circuit current across a and b?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, dc, current-measurement, thevenin

[image]
In order to find R thevenin, I need to find Isc across a and b since there's a dependent source.
Based on my calculations, Vth=500/3V.
I've spent countless hours thinking about Isc,please help.

Comment: Please show all of your work so far. -1 for taking a poor photo and not cropping.

Comment: indeed,that was poor from my part,I will use circuit lab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I strongly recommend actually assigning names (like \$R_1\ldots R_4\$) to your resistors. It makes talking about schematics much easier.

Anyway, when shorting a-b, your 10 Ω becomes irrelevant.

All the current from the current source goes through that short, so while we have to add that current to the total current through the a-b short in the end, it doesn't interfere with the rest of the calculation. So, you build a "helper" circuit.

Thus, all you have to do is calculate the current through R3 in this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fskRyl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage across R2 (or across R3) is your v_x; I'm sure you can solve this :)